# Kill a script if parameters = x

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement

I need to add some Fault Detection or safe guards into one of my bash scripts.

Example if a file has x many lines, that I need the script to not run.

To be more precise. I have a script that compares two files, one of active users vs active accounts and creates or suspends them accordingly.

If one of those files fails to populate it will cause the suspension to be about 20,000 users.

I need to build in something that says if the suspend file has more than 1,000 lines exit the script.

Comment: `wc -l` can count lines in a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on cdhowie's comment, you can do the following check in `bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(wc -l < FILE_NAME_HERE) -ge 1000 ]]; then
   echo "Exiting ..."
   exit
fi;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try:

```
(($(grep -c '.' file) > 1000)) && exit
```

The above counts non-empty lines. To count all lines (empty too) use:

```
(($(grep -c '' file) > 1000)) && exit
```